# Package mnras Warning: Unknown option `a4paper' on input line 113

Tags: pdftex, document-classes

This is my first time ever working with `LaTeX`, and google has so far given me only one result with this error (and that person fixed it by just using `pdfLaTeX` rather than `LaTeX`; both give me the same error).

The document class in the template I'm using is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,usenatbib,useAMS]{mnras}
```

None of that was edited by me. That's a straight copy/paste from the template.

Here's what terminal spits out:

```
Document Class: mnras 2015/05/22\ v3.0\ LaTeX2e MNRAS document class
MNRAS document style v3.0, released 2015/05/22

Package mnras Warning: Unknown option `a4paper' on input line 113.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty
```

Every time I try to run `latex` or `pdflatex` to create a document, it gives me the error in the title. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Apparently your document class doesn't allow to use this option (since probably it has hard coded page layout). Simply, don't use this option.

Comment: @Zarko It is loading `geometry`. Not using that option is not good advice if it is in the template provided!

Comment: The warning is harmless. Simply ignore the warning but include the option as directed. The warning is telling you that the class itself does not recognise the option. But that's fine, because the class apparently loads `geometry` (unless you added this) which *does* know `a4paper` and will proceed accordingly. If you omit the option, you'll get US letter paper, whereas the journal appears to want A4. So keep the option and ignore the warning. Again, ***unless*** you added `geometry` yourself, which would be a whole different kettle of tofu.

Comment: It won't actually do any harm if you omit the option, as it happens, because the class does `\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}` anyway. (It shouldn't use `\usepackage` but it'll work.) However, I would leave the class option in case other packages need to pick it up.

Comment: @cfr, I must confess that I newer use this document class (and it is very low probability that I will ever use it). In my comment I use simple logic: if use of this option cause warning, than this document class don't anticipated this option. Conclusion: not use it :-). However, if for some reason this option is used by packages called with this document class, than the class is not well designed (well, for this OP is not guilty). And warning, as you stated, is harmless.

Comment: The class is quite strange: instead of `\DeclareOption{foo}{...}` it uses `\def\ds@foo{...}`; then it does `\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,...}`, without having defined the `a4paper` option. Only after it it does `\DeclareOption*`.

Comment: @egreg I thought it was strange also. It even contains a note saying that the `\ExecuteOptions` line doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: @Zarko I beg to differ. Such warnings do not necessarily mean a class is poorly designed.Certain ways of processing options - including those provided by L3 - produce these warnings, even though the options are handled properly by the class. Currently, not all legitimate ways of handling options are recognised. Also, there are legitimate reasons to pass options to the class even when the class itself doesn't handle them. I think you are rather quick to judge. *They are warnings - not errors.* Sometimes you want those warnings, even though there *may* be nothing wrong if the class can't tell.

Comment: @cfr How do I tell if the warning is truly harmless? The document throws "underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active" errors on nearly every figure, and none of the google results for fixing that error are comprehensible to me. For one of them, the caption width is the linewidth while the figure width is the textwidth (attempting to set the caption width to textwidth by adding a [width=\textwidth] to \caption doesn't change anything).

Comment: @ChrisB I'm talking about warnings that global class options are ignored by the class. That has nothing to do with bad boxes. In general, bad box warnings are not harmless and should not be ignored. The vast majority can be easily eliminated. (Very occasionally, I think it isn't worth it where doing so would require a lot of energy, I know why I'm getting a bad box and I know it doesn't matter. You shouldn't ignore them unless you know that for sure, however.)